# Protractor ignoring specs passed in a callback function

Tags: protractor

I'm running into an issue and need your help.
I have a list of products and I want to run some it blocks for each product.

The function getProducts is an asynchronous function. Here is my code.

```
jsonLoader = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   beforeAll(function(done) {
       getProducts(function(loadedProducts) {
           resolve(loadedProducts);
           done();
       });
  });
});

describe('product-maintenance', function() {

    jsonLoader.then(function(products) {
        productsList = products;
        //productsList contains the desired products
        _.forOwn(productsList, function(product) {
              //execute it-blocks
        });
    });

   it('some test', function() {
        expect(1).toBe(1);
   });
});
```

He is only executing the it 'some test' and simply ignoring the it blocks in the _.forOwn loop.

Thanks !!! :)

Comment: are you sure > productsList = products; is syntactically correct?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). It is not the problem. I can remove it and iterate directly through products. It stills ignore the it-blocks. Product get printed in each iteration, only the it-blocks are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using promises in the onPrepare function.

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    getProducts(function(products) {
        if (!products) {
            deferred.reject(new Error('An error occured while loading products'));
        } else {
            productsModule.setProducts(products);
            deferred.fulfill();
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```